# How can I return a message when I get no results from my filter?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-filters

I have set up  page that shows different products. I've made a search box with a `ng-model="query"` and whenever I type my query the page gets automatically updated to the products that I have.

The problem is that whenever the query doesn't match something the page stays blank and this doesn't look good. Instead of a blank page I want the site to display a message saying along the lines of "No products found". How can I achieve this?

I've looked at other questions and their solutions but they didn't work.

Here is my code for the way the products are displayed. As you can see I've added a `ng-show="products.length === 0` as some solutions suggested but the message never appears when I don't have a match.

```
        <ul class="list-group">
        <li ng-repeat="product in products | filter:query" class="list-group-item">
            <h3><a id="productName" href="#/products/{{product.name}}">{{ product.name }}</a></h3>
            <img id="mainImage" ng-src="{{ product.imgUrl }}" alt="{{ product.name}}">
            <p id="description"> {{ product.description }}</p>
            <p id="price"> Price: {{ product.price }} £</p>
            <p ng-show="products.length === 0">Nothing found</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is my controller code for the products page:

```
//Controller that fetches the available products to display them in the view
app.controller('productListController', function($scope, $http){
$http.get('products/products.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.products = data.products;
    });
});
```

Here is the code for the search box:

```
<div id="searchbox">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="query" placeholder="Search for...">
            <span style="width=1%;" class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
            </span>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- searchbox -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer @Daniel is not entirely correct.

As you `ng-repeat` to use a `filter`, this `filter` must also be applicable to the condition of `ng-show`.

Like this:

```
<ul> 
 <li ng-repeat="product in products | filter:query" class="list-group-item">
  <h3><a id="productName" href="#/products/{{product.name}}">{{ product.name }}</a></h3>
  <img id="mainImage" ng-src="{{ product.imgUrl }}" alt="{{ product.name}}">
  <p id="description"> {{ product.description }}</p>
  <p id="price"> Price: {{ product.price }} £</p>
 </li>
</ul>
<p ng-show="products && (products| filter:query).length === 0">Nothing found</p>
```

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/mp85bsur/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.search = {};
    $scope.arr = [];
    $scope.isLoaded = false;
    $scope.load = function() {
    $scope.isLoaded = true;
      $scope.arr = [{
        x: 1
      }, {
        x: 2
      }, {
        x: 3
      }, {
        x: 11
      }, {
        x: 12
      }];
    };
    $scope.clear = function() {
      $scope.isLoaded = false;
      $scope.arr = [];
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input ng-model="search.x">
    <button ng-click="load()">
      Load array
    </button>
    <button ng-click="clear()">
      Clear array
    </button>
    <div ng-repeat="a in arrFiltered = (arr|filter:search)">
      {{a.x}}
    </div>
    <div ng-show="isLoaded && arrFiltered.length==0">
      not found
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i updated my answer, with avoidance of filtering twice.

Answer (score 3):

Take the `<p ng-show="products.length === 0">Nothing found</p>` outside the `ng-repeat`.

```
<li ng-repeat="product in filteredProducts = (products | filter:query)" class="list-group-item">
    <h3><a id="productName" href="#/products/{{product.name}}">{{ product.name }}</a></h3>
    <img id="mainImage" ng-src="{{ product.imgUrl }}" alt="{{ product.name}}">
    <p id="description"> {{ product.description }}</p>
    <p id="price"> Price: {{ product.price }} £</p>
</li>
<p ng-show="filteredProducts.length === 0">Nothing found</p>
```

It doesn't show because the `ng-repeat` is empty.

EDIT:

In order to be sure that the msg is displayed after `products` data is loaded:

```
$http.get('products/products.json').success(function(data){
       $scope.products = (data.products && data.products.length > 0) ? data.products : [];
    });
});
```

Comment: I've already tried that but it doesn't show anything again. Also if I change it to `ng-show="products.length"` it will show the Nothing found message even when the filter return zero elements.

Comment: Can you share your controller's code? and showing "no results found" when filter returns empty results sounds like the correct behaviour to me, isn't it?

Comment: What I meant is that if I change it to `ng-show="products.length" the message will appear at the bottom of the page when the page load, that means when the are results returned from the search, but it will also be there when there are no results returned. I will update my question with the controller for the products page but there is nothing about the search function in the controller.

Comment: Updated my answer, i believe this should solve the problem, if i understood it correctly.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. I can't figure out where the problem might be. Here is my github profile with the latest code: https://github.com/konsvasi/companySite/tree/searchMessage you can take a look at the other files, maybe you can spot an error. Maybe there is something wrong with the `products.json` file.

Comment: Ok upadted my answer to show the msg when filtered list is empty thanks to @Stepan Kasyanenko. what problem exactly hasn't been solved yet? do you see the msg before `products` is loaded? do you not see it when the response is empty? do you not see it when the filtered list is empty?

Comment: After putting the line of @Stepan Kasyanenko it is working. Thanks to both of you.